# Add version of installed package from composer in parameters.yml

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php

We work with Symfony v2.7.2 and have `composer.json` to install packages.

Now the desired behaviour is that after or during `composer install`, we want to store the version of a particular package as a parameter in `parameter.yml` (in order to use it in several services for tracking purposes).

I wonder how best to do that?

I could read the value from the `composer.lock` file but then:

How to update the parameter value as the container will be locked after loading?

Is there somehow a way to define a package version as variable to use it in the 'buildParameters' section of `composer.json`?

How can I create/update the parameter with a dynamic value?

Comment: I suspect you will need to write your own little script like the ones in composer scripts section.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution would be to use [composer's scripts](https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/scripts.md) functionality.

Also, keep in mind that most libraries/packages have some sort of constant in a file somewhere that keeps the value of its version. The library you're trying to do this for probably has something similar as well. I recommend looking for it, because it would be a much simpler solution.

For example, [here](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/Kernel.php#L62) are the constants that store Symfony's version.

Answer (score 0):

I would invite you to think of it in a different way.
The libraries usually have a Version Class which has exactly what you need, if you need it to be a parameter you can do it via the Symfony Bundle configuration/extension, and then there is no need to set it under parameters.yml.

That's is the approach I would use.